# How to adjust inner container height in fieldset with legend? (CSS)

Tags: css, height, legend, fieldset

I try to create groupbox with scrollable content in chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/66a8V/.

```
    <!-- language-all: lang-html -->
    <fieldset style="width:400px; height: 200px">
        <legend>Groupbox</legend>
        <div style="overflow: hidden; width:100%; height: 100%">
            <div style="overflow:scroll; width:100%; height: 100%">
                <h1>Content</h1>
                <h1>Content</h1>
                <h1>Content</h1>
                <h1>Content</h1>
                <h1>Content</h1>
                <h1>Content</h1>
                <h1>Content</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

Groupbox size is not fixed.

Fieldset measures inner available height without legend. How to fit inner div size?

Comment: You are fitting all available height. What's the problem?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want this to look like (by using fixed heights)?

Comment: In chrome i have content outside borders, in FF i have normal adjusted content